# using dropdown lists to control forms

Tags: html

I want to use dropdown lists to control the format of a menu I want to create. I've searched the web for several hours now without success. 
We're looking to create a form with its format controllable by a dropdown menu. 
I've created a very simple web form below using html code below to demonstrate;

What we're looking to do is present the form to the user dependent upon their selection of the "Number of Applicants" dropdown. So that if the user selects 1, only the "Applicant 1 Title" dropdown is presented. Should the user select 2, then both the "Applicant 1 Title" and "Applicant 2 Title" dropdowns are presented to the user.

Is this something anyone has come across on here?

```html
 <html>
    <body>
    <form/>
    
    <label for="txt_appnos">Number of Applicants:</label>          
    <select id="txt_appnos" name="appnos">
      <option value="appnos1">1</option>
      <option value="appnos2">2</option>
    </select> 
    <br>     
    <br>     
    
     
    <label for="txt_title1">Applicant 1 Title:</label>          
    <select id="txt_title1" name="title1">
      <option value="MR1">MR</option>
      <option value="MRS1">MRS</option>
      <option value="MISS1">MISS</option>
      <option value="MS1">MS</option>
    </select>      
    
    <br>     
    <br>     
    
    <label for="txt_title2">Applicant 2 Title:</label>          
    <select id="txt_title2" name="title2">
      <option value="MR2">MR</option>
      <option value="MRS2">MRS</option>
      <option value="MISS2">MISS</option>
      <option value="MS2">MS</option>
    </select> 
    
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```js
$('#appnos').on('change', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('#form1').hide();
    $('#form2').hide();
    $('#' + val).show();
});
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="txt_appnos">Number of Applicants:</label>          
<select id="appnos" name="appnos">
  <option value="form1">1</option>
  <option value="form2">2</option>
</select> 
<br>     
<br>     


<form id="form1" class="hidden">
<label for="txt_title1">Applicant 1 Title:</label>          
<select id="txt_title1" name="title1">
  <option value="MR1">MR</option>
  <option value="MRS1">MRS</option>
  <option value="MISS1">MISS</option>
  <option value="MS1">MS</option>
</select> 
</form>     

<form id="form2" class="hidden">
<label for="txt_title2">Applicant 2 Title:</label>          
<select id="txt_title2" name="title2">
  <option value="MR2">MR</option>
  <option value="MRS2">MRS</option>
  <option value="MISS2">MISS</option>
  <option value="MS2">MS</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply Gauthaman, however, that doesn't work for me. It looks like you're using Java Script in there. However, is there a way to do this by using HTML code only?

Comment: basically we need to get the event of your drop down; with only HTML I doubt if that is possible (I have very limited knowledge with HTML). may be some other pros can be of help. Good luck.